# Output PDF file contents stored as BLOB using AJAX call without creating the file

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, pdf

I need to open a pdf file for the user who clicks on a download button.

The download button makes a ajax call to a servlet which gets data from a blob field in the database containing PDF contents, and returns it as a response.

What can I do in order to make the response to be downloaded as a PDF file to the user.

The servlet code is as below:

```
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                oracle.sql.BLOB blob = (BLOB) rs.getBlob("MYPDF");
                byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
                ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                servletOutputStream.flush();
                servletOutputStream.close();
```

I receive a long response containing characters like the ones below in AJAX when I checked the Fire bug for the response.

> �a�J��㔎��ji�2K���y�2��q   F�f�9�G��!%�kɂ��W��������mp){h̕�S���Ǌ_�A����'����2k��j���яR�>wB�e�|=w�p�%w��qǦ>�~�1o�㾙9j�B�;aNx3�`z��طc�O��ï��$�;�N|;�xۇ��;�-�c�f�M��c���(�f�M6K���

**I don't want to submit the page or to popup a window for the servlet with the parameters sent for the query showing in the URL**

> **I also don't want to create the file on the server.**

Is there a way to take the response of servlet coming in ajax call and display it to a page or Iframe and the browser automatically downloads the file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its is NOT possible to download a file using Ajax. However, the same 'effect' can be achieved using a hidden IFRAME. Instead of using XMLHttpRequest, dynamically create a hidden iframe and submit it to the servlet with the proper parameters. When the response comes, the browser will automatically handle the content based on the content-type/extension.  If you are using jQuery, then [this plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) has this functionality in-built.

Comment: `document.getElementById('myform_1').target = 'content_frame'; and the submitting the form` did the trick....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Rahulmohan knows his stuff but it might be worth trying to add a filename header to your response stream.  I do something similar in asp.net but not in an Ajax environment and the only difference between my code and yours is this line:

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Filename & ".pdf")

My page doesn't run in an Ajax environment though.

Comment: as per the http specs, browsers are supposed to handle the response solely based on the response content-type. But, as with any other specs, they are not followed to the letter. For example, IE handles the content based on file extension and not content type. After several trial and errors on various browsers, it was seen that using both file-name with correct extension AND the proper content-type is the best thing to do. But, as I said earlier iframes have to be used.

Comment: I don't doubt you're correct Rahulmohan but I'm not exactly sure I follow your suggestion, I might need to do this myself sometime in the future so I want to make sure I'm following you.  Do you create a hidden iFrame that hosts the page which will write the output to the response stream and then update that by posting it a URL that contains the parameters of which file to write?